# Styling the LightningChart JS chart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I would like to style my LightningChart JS chart graph to look like a graph paper (as shown in the link below without the axis ticks). However, I am unable to control the no of grid lines. Can someone please point me to where they are located?

[image: Sample graph Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no method to control the number of grid lines shown. The grid lines are automatically fitted based on the data and size of chart.

There is plans to expose the tick/grid line positioning logic to allow this kind of custom implementations but it is planned to be implemented only after LightningChart JS 2.0 release.

Comment: When would you release the 2.0 release